# 20.04 - How to completely uninstall iRedMail

Tags: server, 20.04, uninstall

I can't figure out how to remove iRedMail - can someone please help?

I keeps starting on startup, eating all my RAM and disrupting my webserver.

Comment: If you click on the "Show Applications" icon (the 9 dots) and type Startup you can select the graphical overview of all applications which are activated on startup. Is iRedMail included in this overview? If so, you can deactivate it here and it won't get started once you reboot your computer. Note: this will prevent iRedMail from starting at reboot, but does not remove this application from your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postfix* nginx* sa-compile* dovecot* fail2ban* ldap* mysql* sogo* clamav* amavis* nginx* php* mlmmj*

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

sudo rm -rf /var/run/mysql /var/run/amavis /var/run/mlmmjadmin /var/run/iredadmin /var/run/fail2ban /var/run/netdata

sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /etc/clamav /etc/dovecot /etc/fail2ban /etc/netdata /etc/spamassassin

sudo userdel -f iredadmin
sudo userdel -f iredapd
sudo userdel -f clamav
sudo userdel -f mlmmj
sudo userdel -f netdata
sudo userdel -f vmail
sudo userdel -f debian-spamd
sudo userdel -f mail
```

Comment: Since this would effectively remove -amongst others- your webserver, database server, php and antivirus I would not find this a good solution. 

If I would run this on my web, mail- and database server -on which I installed iRedMail- this would totally destroy it!

Comment: This will indeed destroy your webserver.

Comment: This is why I prefer dockerized applications.

Comment: Some folder removals are missing. You also need to run this command along with the rest of them: `sudo rm -rf /opt/iredapd /opt/iRedAPD-5.1 /opt/mlmmjadmin /opt/mlmmjadmin-3.1.5 /opt/netdata /opt/www`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did in order to uninstall all the packages installed by iRedMail (I prefer to uninstall them separately):

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove dovecot-core`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove dovecot-core`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove postfix`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove postfix`

Before continuing to uninstall nginx, please make sure that you have backed up your current server setups (config files, available sites, etc), then proceed.

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove nginx*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nginx*`

---

I have installed MariaDB as my default database. So if you have installed anything else skip this part. Before continuing to uninstall MariaDB, please make sure that you have backed up your current databases using this command lines:

`$sudo mysqldump -u root -p database_name > database_name_date_time.sql`

(For later recovering it, use:

`$mysql -u root –p database_name < database_name_date_time.sql`)

Just replace database_name with your database names. Now you can uninstall MariaDB and MySQL.

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove maria*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove maria*`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mysql*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mysql*`

---

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove sa-compile*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sa-compile*`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ldap*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ldap*`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove sogo*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sogo*`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove clamav*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove clamav*`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove amavis*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove amavis*`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mlmmj*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mlmmj*`

`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove fail2ban*`

`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove fail2ban*`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postfix* nginx* sa-compile* dovecot* fail2ban* ldap* slapd* mysql* sogo* clamav* amavis* nginx* php* mlmmj*
```

# Copy output of this command to a file, find and delete non-empty directories

```
    sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

    sudo rm -rf /var/run/mysql /var/run/amavis /var/run/mlmmjadmin /var/run/iredadmin /var/run/fail2ban /var/run/netdata /var/vmail

    sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /etc/clamav /etc/dovecot /etc/fail2ban /etc/netdata /etc/spamassassin /etc/ldap

sudo rm -rf /opt/iredapd* /opt/iRedAPD* /opt/mlmmjadmin* /opt/netdata* /opt/www*

sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f iredadmin\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f iredapd\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f clamav\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f mlmmj\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f netdata\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f vmail\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f debian-spamd\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f mail\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f postgres\
sudo deluser --remove-all-files -f openldap
```

# Kill process for deluser failure and remove user again

```
rm -rf /root/.iredmail /root/iRedMail* /root/.ldap* /root/.my.cnf* /root/.wget*
```

# Reboot if you prefer